# How to modify ArrayList object if one of its field contain duplicate entries?

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist, collections

I have an `ArrayList` of type model class .Model class contain two fields
for Ex: `number` and `name`.

If the `number` is appearing multiple times then I need to append its corresponding `name` so that the `number` has to be a unique in `ArrayList`?

Lets say:

```
list.get(0).getNumber = 100,

list.get(0).getName   = Narendra.

list.get(1).getNumber = 100,

list.get(1).getName   = Modi.

list.get(2).getNumber = 101,

list.get(2).getName   = xyz.
```

So my final list should contain only two items i.e.

```
list.get(0).getNumbet =100,

list.get(0).getName = Narendra Modi.

list.get(1).getNumbet =101,

list.get(1).getName = xyz.
```

Comment: You could use a map instead (if it needs to maintain insertion order use a `LinkedHashmap`, if you need some different order use `TreeMap`). Then use the number value as the key and do a lookup first.

Comment: @ Thomas can you show me snippet.

Comment: ArrayList can have duplicate entries, though if you need unique keys for example,  Map would be a better choice.  There is millions of example on the web.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you really want is a multi-map.  You can do this in plain Java 8 with

```
final Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

public void put(Integer num, String name) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(num, n -> new HashSet<>()).add(name);
}

put(100, "Narendra");
put(100, "Modi");
put(101, "xyz"):
```

Answer (score 0):

With traditional java versions, you can use map as below:

```
    Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    if(m.get(100) != null){
        m.put(100,"Narendra");          
    }
    else{
        m.put(100, (m.get(100)+" Modi"));
    }
```